# How do a muslim woman pray if she doesn’t have a hijab?

Tags: salat, women, hijab

I’ve watched a film based on a true incident where a muslim girl’s plane crashed and she ended up in a forest. She’s got some minor injuries & some of her clothes were ripped including her hijab. So she was all alone & she didn’t have anything to cover her head & her arm.

In that kind of situation what should the girl do? She doesn’t have access to anything at all. How was she supposed to pray? From what I’ve read, a muslim woman should wear a hijab in order to perform her prayers.

Comment: That depends on the circumstances. Basically any tissue or material that covers the whole body except with face and hands will do. In some cases some scholars allow praying even nakedly and in some cases you may pray on time as you are and repeat later depending on the scholarly view and Allah knows best. And finally if one wants to cover him- or herself one usually finds a solution by improvising except there's nothing useful for that like in deserts.

Answer (score 4):

Improvise. There is a lot of usable material available in a forest, the most basic of which is foliage . There is a precedent for this:

> So he made them fall, through deception. And when they tasted of the
>   tree, their private parts became apparent to them, and **they began to
>   fasten together over themselves from the leaves of paradise**.
>
> ([7:22](https://quran.com/7/22))